# Mysql Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Can't figure out how a query such as the following one can throw such error in MySql.

```
INSERT INTO

tbl1.monthlydata(Led,
Lev2,
Date,
Dimension,
Dimension1,Currency,
CurrAmount,
Amount)


values('999999','AA9999','2020-01-01','6666','AAAAAAA','STR',10,10)
```

there is no aggregating function and if I try to enter manually the same values in the table it works

Comment: Maybe you have a trigger on your table which causes the error?

Comment: fantastic, I deleted the trigger and it works. I'd like to understand the logic of this.

Comment: What logic? An insert trigger fires on an insert - what else do you need to know?

Comment: I don't get how a trigger can prevent data from being loaded to a specific table via a insert query, but if the same data is manually entered then the trigger lets you do that.

Comment: The trigger is a piece of code that **always** runs at a specific event on your table, and it can perform other queries like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc. More likely the error was on a select performed by the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error probably happened because of a trigger on your table, which was being executed after your `INSERT` command.

Triggers are pieces of code that always execute upon a predefined event on your table, and may execute queries of their own. Likely, the "invalid use of group function" error on your insert was caused by a `SELECT` query with aggregate functions on your trigger.

But, since you deleted it, the error is lost.